# How to compute the number of operations of jacobi iteration in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to compute the number of operations of jacobi iteration in matlab
I do not know how to do it !!!
Can you help me ?
Thanks

Here is my code for newton method :

```
b=zeros(30,1);
b(6)=2;
alpha=1;
A=zeros(30,30);
A(1,1)=-(2+alpha);
A(1,2)=1;

for ii=2:29
    A(ii,ii-1)=1
    A(ii,ii)=-(2+alpha)
    A(ii,ii+1)=1
end

A(30,29)=1;
A(30,30)=-(2+alpha);

D=diag(diag(A));
R=A-D;
x=zeros(30,1);

for ii=1:100
    xk= inv(D)*(b-R*x);
    if(norm(xk-x,1)<=10^-5) 
        break;
    end
    x=xk;
end

ii
```

Comment: At first, change all `i` variables with different index - it overrides the imaginary unit! Use `ii`, `i1`,`ci` istead. Same is valid for `j`.What does your last `i` return?

Comment: I get this `i =28`

Comment: If the last loop perform Jacobi iterations then `ii` returns the count of iterations.

Comment: so operations of jacobi iteration is ii ??

Comment: when I put for ii=1:100 then ii is printed 100 but when for i=1:10000 then ii is printed 10000 so ii depends on the for loop length ... it is strange

Comment: in the `for` loop, defined by `for ii=1:100` the `ii` variable is the counter. You can use `for ii=0:3:300` but you will lose the couter behaviour. Since it will use values of `[0,3,6,...,300]` instead of `[1,2,3,...,100]`

Comment: I did what you mentioned but there is no understandable answer

Comment: This shows that the `for` loop was terminated by reaching the end of `ii`. If it would be terminated by `return` prompt it will display last value of `ii` used in the loop.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code with `ii`s instead of `i`s?

Comment: I edited it .. when I write `return ii` matlab says : `Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.`

Comment: The error is caused because `return` command stops execunting running functions and forces to return actual values assigned to the output.

Comment: how to correct it please

Comment: I've run your editted code and it returned `ii = 28`. The last `for` loop was run 28 times.

Comment: so operations of jacobi iteration is `ii  = 28`??!!

Comment: Yes. And end the lines in first loop by semicolons, Try `xk=D\(b-R*x);` and do not forget to update `x=xk` before you `break` the loop. The last suggestion prevents losing results from last interation - the loop execution is terminated right where `break` prompt is.

Comment: you can provide an answer to this and I vote for you so that I understand better .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have counted it, actually.

In case of code

```
for ii=1:N
  %% Code
end
```

the `ii` variable works like the counter.

Reading the code step-by-step you:

1. Define anonymous temporary array, say `forII` with elements 1 to N with default step of 1.
2. For each iteration the appropriate element of original `forII` is assigned to `ii`
3. `%% Code` is executed
4. New value of `ii` scalar is assigned.

This behaviour allows:

1. Use `counter=1:N` as true counter.
2. Loop easily over elements of any array, for example `for foo='Hello World!'`.
3. Use predefined indices, array elements, etc. `for ii=A`.
4. When the `for` loop is terminated by `break` or `return` prompt the elements in *queue* are not assigned and ii keeps the last assigned value.

You can try

```
kk=0;
for ii=1:N
  kk=kk+1;
  if ii==5
    break
  end
end
disp(['kk = ' num2str(kk) '; ii = ' num2str(ii)]);

kk=0;
for ii='Hello World!'
  kk=kk+1;
  if ii=='r'
    break
  end
end
disp(['kk = ' num2str(kk) '; ii = ' num2str(ii)]);
```